# setup 404 page using $routeProvider in angular js

Tags: angularjs, routes

Working on single page application everything is working fine but getting stuck when want to set 404 page when `:username` not found or any unexpected url will load in browser please check my code below

**controller.js**

```
    var myApp = angular.module('assignment', ['ngRoute']);

    myApp.service('userData', ['$http', function($http){
      return{
        userslist : function(){
            return $http({'url' : 'js/data.json', 'method' : 'GET'}).then(function(response){
            return response.data;
          }, function(data){
            console.log('some error')
          })
        }
      }
    }]);


      myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'user-list.html',
            controller: 'users'
          }).
          when('/:username', {
            templateUrl: 'detail.html',
            controller: 'userdetail'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/404.html' /*>>>>>>Here is the problem<<<<<<*/
          });
      });



    myApp.controller('userdetail', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'userData', function($scope, $routeParams, userData){

var selectedUser = $routeParams.username;
selectedUser = selectedUser.replace(/-/g, ' ');



  userData.userslist().then(function(data){
    $scope.items = [];

    angular.forEach(data.data.bst_users, function(item){
          if(item.name == selectedUser) {
             $scope.user = item;
           };

    })

  })
}])



    myApp.controller('userdetail', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'userData', function($scope, $routeParams, userData){
    console.log($routeParams.username);

    userData.find($routeParams.username, function(found){

        $scope.user = found;
    })

    console.log(scope.user)

    }])


    /*******Filters*******/

    myApp.filter('removeSpace',function() {
        return function(input) {
            if (input) {
                return input.replace(/\s+/g, '-');    
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have 2 `userdetail` controllers, don't know if that was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared `/:username` as a route, it can match anything after the `/`, meaning the 404 route isn't really doing anything and the username route in a sense is acting as your catch-all route. This is kind of a weird case, since you can't really define a regular 404 route. But what you could do is have a `/404` route, then if `/:username` doesn't resolve to a user, redirect them to /404. That is the most efficient method I can come up with, but I guarantee there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

@Jordan points out a definite issue.

I would recommend updating your user detail path to something like the following:

```
when('/user/:username', {
  templateUrl: 'detail.html',
  controller: 'userdetail'
})
```

Just so there is no confusion between `/random_username` and `/unmatched_path`.